# Schengen visa for Sweden and Denmark

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, applications, itineraries

I'm really lost about how to fill my form, as I have an invitation from my GF from Sweden, but the closest place to her is Copenhagen, not Stockholm.

Should I fill Denmark as my first entry, and leave from Denmark also, and provide my train booking to her with my application?

Comment: Do you mean where you will apply for your Schengen visa? If so, you need to apply at the country which is the main stay, and visiting your girlfriend is more important than entering and leaving as soon as possible. But you may look at something else. Please give us more details.

Comment: im going apply on Sweden agency. but  is this gonna bring problems if my entry is Danmark and Sweden visa

Comment: What kind of agency?

Comment: vfs golbal there where Sweden apply applications in

Comment: @kali bell If I’ve understood your question correctly, your main destination is Sweden but you’ll enter Schengen in Denmark. The rules state that if the travel destination is one Member State, that Member State's consulate must deal with the application. If more than one destination, the application must be dealt with by the consulate of the main destination. The main destination is understood to be the destination where the applicant intends to spend the longest time or where the main purpose of the intended journey is. So you must apply to Sweden. This is normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: thank you so much bro very kind of u helping me

Comment: I've reopened this question because the duplicate did not actually cover the issue identified in this question (but it did require a good deal of work to wade through the 1500-word answer in order to determine that).

Comment: @Traveller The Copenhagen International airport is very close to Sweden, so for much of southern Sweden that would be the go-to-airport.

Comment: @Thorbjorn Ravn Andersen Yes, but that doesn’t change the answer provided by phoog, or the information in my comment (which stated the situation described by the OP is completely normal).

Comment: @Traveller No, this was to clarify why in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I fill Denmark as my first entry, and leave from Denmark also, and provide my train booking to her with my application?

Yes.

> Is this going to bring problems if my entry is Denmark and I have a visa from Sweden?

No.